# latexdiff incompatible with half brackets

Tags: brackets, latexdiff, parentheses

I recently encountered some problem using `latexdiff` when the tex file contains matched half brackets like `\left(\.` or `\.\right)`. For example, I have two files, one is `test-old.tex`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
this is the old one, with

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \left(
    full~bracket
  \right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

the other is `test-new.tex`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
this is the new one, with
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \left(
    half~bracket
  \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I use the command `latexdiff test-old.tex test-new.tex > test-diff.tex` to generate the compared file `test-diff.tex` as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL test-old.tex   Wed Feb  3 21:05:52 2016
%DIF ADD test-new.tex   Wed Feb  3 21:05:58 2016
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
this is the \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{old }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{new }\DIFaddend one, with
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \left(
    \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{full}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{half}\DIFaddend ~bracket
  \DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \right)
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \right\DIFadd{.
}\DIFaddend \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which does not compile to pdf, mainly due to the third line from bottom

```
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \right\DIFadd{.
```

where `\right` is separated from `.`, hence the matching is ruined.

How does this happen? Is there a proper way to avoid this? Thanks!

P.S.

My `latexdiff --version` produces

```
This is LATEXDIFF 1.0.2  (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 so, Perl v5.18.2)
```

which I know is not the latest, but I did not find any related information on this (possible) bug.

---

At this stage, I have tried two methods to at least make `test-diff.tex` compile. One is to modify the file, delete the related part in the generated file(or add a dot manually after `\right`); but this not only adds debugging effort, I have to do it every time after comparison. The other way is to define a new macro for the half brackets(or parentheses), and use the new macro instead in the files to be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple bug in the script, forgetting to add `.` as a possible bracket.  You can correct it by replacing the line starting `my $cmdleftright=` by

```
  my $cmdleftright='\\\\(?:left|right|[Bb]igg?[lrm]?|middle)\s*(?:[<>()\[\]|\.]|\\\\(?:[|{}]|\w+))';
```

The change being to add `\.` in the group `[<>...]`.

You should report this as a bug to the maintainer.

Comment: You are amazing! I guess I cannot test this myself (as I know nothing of perl etc), but I'll try to report the bug as you suggested.

Comment: Another thing I notice is that, if the formulas are inline (between $$), then everything is ok. Why this different standard?

Comment: but not ok if I try `\(\)` or `\[\]`

Comment: @davyjones Those are math environment delimiters, not brackets, so they should not be covered by this.