# What output encoding does `latexdiff` use?

Tags: input-encodings, latexdiff

I'm trying to use `latexdiff` on two versions of a document. These are encoded in UTF8 and have the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` statement as first line within the preamble.

I processed the files then using

```
latexdiff --encoding=utf8 file1.tex file2.tex > out.tex
```

but when I try to open `out.tex` with TexMaker again and I specify UTF8 as encoding, all the characters like `äöüé` show up as some gibberish characters. I assume this means that `latexdiff` does not use UTF8 as output encoding, but what encoding does it use?

This is on Windows 10 using MikTex and TexMaker and Strawberry Perl (doesn't work with Active State Perl either).

---

EDIT: Due to the observations below I have to conclude that latexdiff OR texmaker do not use the correct UTF8 encoding.

I now made two new toy documents in TexMaker (without any umlauts or other special characters), which is set to UTF8 in the settings:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Test1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{intro}
what is love?
\begin{itemize}
\item item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

document2:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Test2}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{intro}
what is hate?
\begin{itemize}
\item item2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Running the command `latexdiff .\doc1.tex .\doc2.tex > diff.tex` results in following `diff.tex` (when opened with TexMaker, selecting UTF8 when asked in the popup). (When I try to paste the text here, nothing is pasted, hence the image.)

[image]

The document does however look correct when I open it with the UTF16 setting:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL .\doc1.tex   Mon Sep 11 13:46:31 2017
%DIF ADD .\doc2.tex   Mon Sep 11 13:46:26 2017
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Test1}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Test2}\DIFaddend }
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{intro}
what is \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{love}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{hate}\DIFaddend ?
\begin{itemize}
\item \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{item
}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{item2
}\DIFaddend \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But as soon as I try to compile it using `pdflatex` I get the error

```
line 1 ! Undefined control sequence. \
```

Comment: @egreg How can you check whether you get the correct format?

Comment: I've never had a problem and I don't even specify the encoding option. (Unless I stuck it in a config file.) And all my files use UTF8 and include at least some non-ASCII characters (curly quotes, if nothing else).

Comment: I simply opened the file with a UTF-8 editor. Not Notepad++, of course, which I cannot run and is known to add a BOM all around.

Comment: On a UNIX-ish system, you can say `file <path>` to get the encoding (and other information) about the file at `<path>`. Not sure on Windows, though.

Comment: Unfortunately the "solution" above does not work for my real documents. The outputs with and without the `--e=utf8` are identical.

Comment: utf8 is the default output format, so that you get the same results with the `--encoding=utf8` option is expected behaviour. Also, latexdiff would have figured the same thing out for input files from \usepackage command. Note that your problem cannot be reproduced by others. So somehow Strawberry Perl's idea of what utf8 is is different from TexMakers. I don't use Windows so cannot help you further. If you know Perl, you could try writing a little test routine just reading and writing your file with encoding. If not, try opening input and output files in a different editor.

Comment: I now tried using active state perl (instead of strawberry), but that still produces the same results.

Comment: @flawr Could be that perl somehow defaults to UTF16 now, even when choosing utf8? Have you tried using `\usepackage[utf16]{inputenc}` (not sure if this is supported).  The diff.tex you pasted compiles for me for me but I think Stack Exchange editor does not preserve the encoding - it shows up as 'ascii' encoding for me.

Comment: @frederik That might indeed be the case - I just looked it up and it seems UCS2 (which is what NP++ says) is a predecessor of UTF16, and for a large part they are identical. Unfortunately `inputenc` [only supports UTF8](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/base/inputenc.pdf). What might work for me though is `latin9` which seems to be supported by all components (not sure about perl), but it is very restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is not really a solution, just a workaround to make get it going, but very cumbersome to use it that way. But perhaps someone can see an issue. So this is the sequence of actions that made it working:

1. Replace all special characters and umlauts with ASCII characters (in my case ÄÖÜäöü with ae,oe,ue, and é with e)
2. Remove all `\left` and `\right` [which is another issue of latexdiff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290911/latexdiff-incompatible-with-half-brackets)
3. Comment out all `tikz` pictures (in my case it was enough to comment all `\tikzsetnextfilename` as well as `%\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]`), [see also here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/force-latexdiff-not-to-parse-tikzpicture-environments).
4. Run `latexdiff .\doc1.tex .\doc2.tex > diff.tex`
5. Open `diff.tex` with NotePad++. The current encoding is `UCS2-Little-Endian`, but we need to use `Convert to UTF8-without-BOM`, and save the document.
6. Open the `diff.tex` in TexMaker, now no dialog box about encoding should pop up, and the document should compile fine.

Comment: The answer is confusing because points 2-3 are unrelated issues not part of the original question. I suggest deleting those points (and raise them as a separate issue if needed). I still find it very confusing to see this behaviour and wonder whether you have something unusual about your setup; where does the UCS2-Little-Endian encoding come from, for example?

Comment: Regarding 2. This issue was fixed some time ago - which version of latexdiff are you using.

Comment: Regarding 3. Why did you not use the suggestion suggested in the post you linked - seems less cumbersome once it's set up.

Comment: I thought to include them in case someone has the same setup and similar problems. I'm not sure about the UCS2-LE, I read somewhere that NP++ sometimes displays this encoding insted of some other one it does not recognize. The latexdiff is version 1.1903 which came with the most recent MikTex package.